# Grafana + Prometheus: use custom variable as filter of tag values

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have a query from Prometheus like:

```
http_server_requests(uri=...)
```

Now, in Grafana, I want to use a custom variable to let user select waht uri to exclude.

If I use query, it would be:

```
http_server_requests(uri!="url1|url2|url3")
```

Is this possible?

Comment: By custom variable you mean dashboard variable ? Note that your query is wrong, it should be `http_server_requests{uri!~"url1|url2|url3"}`

Comment: Yes you are right; a copy-paste error; though with correct format it does not work neither. By custom variable I mean dashboard var with type "custom", yes.

Comment: Did you try `!~` instead of `!=` ?

Comment: Of course. As I said.

Answer (score 1):

Use [advanced variable formatting](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/variables/advanced-variable-format-options/#pipe) - pipe format:

```
http_server_requests(uri!="${urlsCustomDashboardVariable:pipe}")
```

Comment: Well thanks! but it fails with an error: `Object request:Object
url:"api/datasources/proxy/83/api/v1/query_range?query=sum(http_server_requests_seconds_count%7Buri!%3D%22%24%7Benv%3D%22actuator%2Cpreprod%22%2Coutcome!%3D%22CLIENT_ERROR%22%2CproductName%3D%22checkout-discounts-api%22%2Curi!~%22%2F_system%2Fcheck.*%7C%2Fswagger.*%7C%2Fv2%2Fapi-docs%22%7D)%20by%20(method%2C%20uri)&start=1602662400&end=1602684000&step=7200" errorType:"bad_data" error:"1:53: parse error: unexpected identifier "actuator" in label matching, expected "," or "}""`

Comment: The query is  `sum(http_server_requests_seconds_count{uri !~ "${backoffice_urls:pipe}" }) by (method, uri)`